# Selecting total number of students in each class

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Class: cid, name, location

Student: sid, name, gender, classID

I am attempting to use a select statement to display the class name along with the total number of students in the class. I'm also trying to exclude any class with less than 10 students from the table.

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT
    c.name as className,
    count(s.sid) as totalStudents
  FROM Class c
    JOIN Student s ON s.classID = c.cid
  GROUP BY c.id
  HAVING count(s.sid) >= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.name, count(*)  
from Class as a
inner join Student as b on b.ClassID = a.cid
group by a.name
having count(*) >= 10;
```